# Best Electronics and Robotics Resources for a Novice

Tags: sensor, robotics, software

I know guys hanging around here are quite experienced in electronics and robotics. But I am rather new to this area. I have only A/L physics knowledge in electronics. But I am working as a software engineer. Can anybody tell me the best resources that I can follow to become throughly acquainted with the subject. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same background as you, and one of the first things I bought was an [EasyPIC5](http://www.mikroe.com/eng/products/view/1/easypic5-development-system/) pic microcontroller development board. It allows you to play around with pics without having to know too much about the electronics side.

When you want to build a circuit using your newly programmed pic, you can start by prototyping it on a breadboard... and then move on to soldering it on to stripboard.

You can get lots of circuit schematic ideas by searching on Google images.

Comment: Hi BG100, thanks for your answer. I definitely go through the links provided.

Answer (score 1):

http://hackaday.com/ - this will give you the idea of what can possibly be done in limited resources.

Then get an Arduino and start playing http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/HomePage .

Meanwhile find out local/internet shops where you will be able to buy parts without waiting too long.

Comment: Hi BarsMonster, thanks for your answer. I definitely go through the links provided.

Comment: Great copy&paste ;-)

Answer (score 1):

My professor last year had us buy a [3pi Robot](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/1306). I thought it was a pretty cool beginners robot. There is a lot of documentation and even a user forum on Pololu's website.

If you get an expansion board, you will have more space to add sensors or more sophisticated circuitry.

Comment: Hi Ryan, thanks for your answer. I definitely go through the links provided.

Answer (score 1):

Another great place for a beginner is  [Letsmakerobots.com](http://letsmakerobots.com/), the site is geared more toward the hobbyist/hacker crowd.

Comment: Hi jsolarski, thanks for your answer. I definitely go through the links provided.

Answer (score 1):

Trossen Robotics has some [excellent forums](http://forums.trossenrobotics.com) for getting your questions answered. Both [BotJunkie](http://botjunkie.com) and [Robots-Dreams](http://www.robots-dreams.com) are two good blogs for keeping up with robotics news.

There are several very good robotics communities which you should check out, [Letsmakerobots](http://letsmakerobots.com) and [DIY Drones](http://diydrones.com) are two of the best. I've also created a site ([RobotBox](http://robotbox.net)) where robot builders post their projects. You might get some inspiration there.

For purchasing parts, I recommend [Trossen Robotics](http://trossenrobotics.com), [Pololu](http://pololu.com), [Solarbotics](http://solarbotics.com), or [Lynxmotion](http://www.lynxmotion.com). Those folks have been around for a long time. There are tons of smaller specialty outfits, but you can explore those as you gain knowledge.

Comment: Hi gallamine, Thank you very much for your lengthy answer. I definitely will follow the links you've provided. Thanks again.